# Batch file to copy section from one text file to others text files

Tags: batch-file

I need to search an specific string in a text file and copy a text section between two lines containing my string to others text file.

Example: suppose my control string is "my_string" and the text in my file is:

```
1st line text
2nd line text my_string more text
3rd line text
4th line text
5th line text my_string more text
6th line text
7th line text
8th line text my_string more text
9th line text
10th line text
```

So as output I want to have three files:

File 1:

```
2nd line text my_string more text
3rd line text
4th line text
```

File 2:

```
5th line text my_string more text
6th line text
7th line text
```

File 3:

```
8th line text my_string more text
9th line text
10th line text
```

Does anybody know how to do this using batch files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a destadd=0
SET "mystring=my_string"
SET "found="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22047584.txt) DO (
 ECHO("%%a"|FIND "%mystring%" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET found=Y&set/a destadd+=1)
 IF DEFINED found >>"file !destadd!" ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should do the task - data in `q22047584.txt` and output in "file 1".."file 3" as requested.

`File ?` is assumed to not already exist when the routine is executed.

---

Amendment to accommodate extended question

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "mystring=my_string"
SET "found="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22047584.txt) DO (
 ECHO("%%a"|FIND "%mystring%" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET found=Y
  SET "destadd=%%a"
  SET "destadd=!destadd:*%mystring%=!"
  )
 IF DEFINED found >>"!destadd!" ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

There are dangers with this procedure however. It assumes that the-remainder-of-the-line forms a valid unique filename - unlike your sample data.

Oh - and far easier to respond to the entire question rather than chasing shifting goalposts.

Comment: And if I want to save each file with the text after my_string in the same line as the file name instead of "File 1", "File 2"...?