# Parse JSON File with batch script

Tags: json, parsing

sorry for my english, I'm Italian and I'm using Goole Translator.
I have this problem: I have a rather complex JSON file, with a very branched structure.
The general structure is similar to the one of C drive of every PC: the root can have several subfolder with different name whose can contain other subfolders with names that could be equal to the one in another 1st level subfolder; each one can contain files or other subfolders

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxOj0.jpg)

I need a batch script to extract some values but as you can see the most nested branches can be equal to each other and consequently I cannot use a simple *findstr* because I would not have unique results.

I thought of two solutions: the first is to ask if there is a pre-made routine that allows me to read a value by simply recalling it, passing as an argument the complete path of the value to be found, for example

*parsejson.bat Subtree5 Subtree6 Subtree3 Value2*.

The second solution is to divide the starting JSON into several blocks corresponding to each 1st subfolder Subtree1, Subtree5... in order to have blocks in which the values of the subtrees are not repeated like in the image I posted before. I know exactly the name of all the six 1st level subfolders.

I found this question on your site [Batch file to copy section from one text file to others text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047584/batch-file-to-copy-section-from-one-text-file-to-others-text-files) which would be perfect for my purpose if only I understood how to use different strings to delimit blocks.
This one can also be usefull [Batch File - Find two lines then copy everything between those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638832/batch-file-find-two-lines-then-copy-everything-between-those-lines) but I must repeat it four times to get the needed result...

Does anyone know how to help me? Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Can't you use node.js or any other language to parse the JSON file and extract the data?

Comment: I cannot use another language because this is only a part of a bigger project that involves other people...